# Simple python multiprocessing pool script error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've tried to get a very simple multiprocessing script to work and am failing to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm utilizing Python 2.7.5 64bit on win32.  I was looking at [Python Multiprocessing help exit on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490137/python-multiprocessing-help-exit-on-condition) for assistance.

Style 1:

```
import multiprocessing

def doCalc(year):
    return year*year

yearlist = [1,2,3,4]
print(yearlist)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

for i in yearlist:
    pool.apply_async(doCalc, args=[i])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Style 2:

```
import multiprocessing

def doCalc(year):
    return year*year

yearlist = [1,2,3,4]
print(yearlist)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

pool.map(doCalc, yearlist)
```

Both scripts print [1,2,3,4] and then do nothing.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do mean mean by "do nothing"? It hangs? The script ends?

Comment: What are you expecting the scripts to do? You're not doing with anything from the results of doCalc, so the only output expected from the script is [1,2,3,4], just like you're seeing.

Comment: It doesn't end and give me a prompt.  It hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, you should run multiprocessing functions inside`if __name__ == "__main__"` ([doc1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class), [doc2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)). So, try this:

```
import multiprocessing

def doCalc(year):
    return year*year

yearlist = [1,2,3,4]
print(yearlist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(doCalc, yearlist)
```