# Python 3: Multiprocessing API calls with exit condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to write an application which works through a list of database entries, making an API call with those, return the value and if one value of the APIs JSON response is `True` for 5 calls, I want to have the list of those 5 calls. As the database entries are a couple of thousand entries, I want to realise this with `multiprocessing`. But I'm a beginner with parallelisation and it seems I can't get the grasp of how it works and how to set the exit condition. Here's what I got:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import requests

def get_api_response(apikey, result, subscription_id):
    r = requests.get("https://api.example.com/" + subscription_id)
    if r.json()['subscribed'] == True:
        result.append(r.json())
        return result

def pass_args(args):
    foo = get_api_response(*args)
    if foo:
        return foo

def check_response_amount(result):
    if len(result) >= 5:
        pool.terminate() 

# One entry looks like that: {"id": 1, "name": "smith", "subscription_id": 123}
db_entries = get_db_entries()
apikey = 'abcd1234'
result = []
request_tuples = [(apikey, result, entry['subscription_id']) for entry in db_entries]
pool = Pool(5)
pool_result = pool.map_async(pass_args, request_tuples, callback=check_response_amount)
pool_result.wait()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The application checks every database entry and returns every api response which has `subscribed == True` without even running through the callback. I tried applying the answer from another question ([Python Multiprocessing help exit on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490137/python-multiprocessing-help-exit-on-condition)), but couldn't get it to work. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `map_async`, the callback won't be executed until every work item in the iterable has completed. If you want the callback to execute for every item in `request_tuples`, rather than only after all of them are done, you need to use `apply_async` inside a for loop instead:

```
results = []
for item in request_tuples:
    results.append(pool.apply_async(get_api_response, args=item, callback=check_response_amount))

for result in results:
    result.wait()
```

Additionally, calling `pool.terminate` isn't going to work the way you want; the items you've already submitted to the pool are going to hang forever once you call it, which will make your script hang, since you're waiting on them to finish before exiting. You can work around this by just waiting on the pool to join, rather than actually waiting on any individual task to finish.

```
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import TERMINATE

def get_api_response(apikey, result, subscription_id):
    url  = ("https://api.example.com/" + str(subscription_id))
    time.sleep(2)
    result.append(url)
    return result

def pass_args(args):
    foo = get_api_response(*args)
    if foo:
        return foo

def check_response_amount(result):
    if result and len(result) >= 5:
        print("DONE %s" % result)
        pool.terminate()


def get_db_entries():
    return [{'subscription_id' : i} for i in range(100)]

# One entry looks like that: {"id": 1, "name": "smith", "subscription_id": 123}
db_entries = get_db_entries()
apikey = 'abcd1234'
result = []
request_tuples = [(apikey, result, entry['subscription_id']) for entry in db_entries]
pool = Pool(2)
results = []
for item in request_tuples:
    results.append(pool.apply_async(get_api_response, item, callback=check_response_amount))
pool.close()
pool.join()
print("done")
```

Output:

```
IN HERE
IN HERE
IN HERE
IN HERE
IN HERE
... (a bunch more of this)...
IN HERE
IN HERE
DONE ['https://api.example.com/1', 'https://api.example.com/0', 'https://api.example.com/2', 'https://api.example.com/3', 'https://api.example.com/4', 'https://api.example.com/5']
done
```

Note that the `result` list can end up being a little bigger than you want, since the `terminate` call won't actually stop in-progress tasks.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please? I tried replacing the pool.map_async line with your snippet, but that didn't fill my `result` list at all. Also is it normal that the execution of the `get_api_response` is only started if I do an iterated `result.get()` over results? This seems strang to me.

Comment: @m3adow Sorry, I had to run to a meeting right after I posted the answer, so I didn't get to test it fully. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I still need to fiddle around a bit, but I got a rough test to work properly. Thanks for your help.