# Graceful Termination of Worker Pool

Tags: python, multithreading, exit, flags, pool

I want to spawn X number of Pool workers and give each of them X% of the work to do. My issue is that the work takes about 20 minutes to exhaust, longer for each extra process running, due to the type of calculations being done my answer may be found within minutes or hours. What I would like to do is implement some way for a single worker to go "HEY I FOUND IT" and use that signal to kill the remainder of the pool and move on with my calculations.

Key points:

- I have tried callbacks, they don't seem to run on a `starmap_async` until the entire pool finishes.
- I only care about the first suitable answer found.
- I am not sharing resources and surprise process death, albeit rude, is perfectly acceptable.

I've also considered using a Queue, but it wouldn't make since because the scope of work I'm passing to each is already built into the parameters of the function.

Below is a very dulled down version of what I'm working with (the calculations I'm working with can take hours to finish over a 4.2 billion complex iterable.)

```
def doWork():
    workers = Pool(2)
    results = workers.starmap_async( func = distSearch , iterable = Sections1_5,  callback = killPool )
    workers.close()
    print("Found answer : {}".format(results.get()))
    workers.join()

def killPool():
    workers.terminate()
    print("Worker Pool Terminated")
```

I should probably specify that my process only returns if it finds an answer otherwise it just exits once done. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490137/python-multiprocessing-help-exit-on-condition) thread but it has my completely lost and seems like a lot of overhead to consistently check for the win condition when that should come in the return/callback of the Worker Pool.

All the answers I've found result in significant overhead by supervising the worker pool, I'm looking for a solution that sources the kill signal at the worker level, autonomously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for a solution that sources the kill signal at the worker level, autonomously.

AFAIK, that doesn't exist. The methods of the `Pool` object (like `Pool.terminate`) should *only* be used in the process that created the pool.

What you could do is use `Pool.imap_unordered`. This returns an iterator *in the parent process* over the results which yields results as soon as they become available. As soon as the desired result pops up, you could then use `Pool.terminate()`.

**Edit**:

- From looking at the 3.5 implementation `starmap_async` returns a `MapResult` instance, which is *not* an iterator.
- You can wrap multiple inputs in a tuple and use `imap_unordered` over a list of those.

Comment: I'm currently using 'starmap_async'.  It yields an iterator but seems to be blocking until all results return.  (Which it shouldnt) .  Is this a known bug? I searched and didn't find any logged issues.  Additionally, does 'imap_unordered' support multiple function inputs?  Last note.  In the code above 'killpool ()' runs immediately after the worker pool completes, I just want it to kill on the first return.

Comment: @DerrickCheek I've edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I will try this when I get home. I must have confused the iterator return. I've had several issues trying to map the multiple inputs and some results give iterators and some don't haha. Hopefully this works. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @DerrickCheek The documentation for the `Pool` methods could certainly use some improvement in that regard. So when in doubt, use the source. :-)